# Android: issue setting the selected item in an Integer Spinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

```
final Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerNumber);
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < 51; j++) {
            list.add(j);
        }

        ArrayAdapter<Integer> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

I want to set a selected Item in this spinner. Usually I do `spinner.setSelection()` inserting the position of the element I want to be setted, inside the `setSelection()`. This time everything I put inside the `setSelection()` doesn't produce any effect and my spinner remains set to 0...what am I missing?

Comment: whats your requirement?

Comment: are you passing any value in `setSelection` method  ...?

Comment: yes of course. imagine that I want to have the number 2 selected I would pass 'setSelection(2)'

Comment: will you show ,how to are trying to set position. Bcoz `spinner.setSelection(2)` will set position in spinner correctly .....

Comment: Now it works...I really have no idea, simply restarted Android Studio and qemu...not sure what happened, btw thanks everybody

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerNumber);
    final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int j = 0; j < 51; j++) {
        list.add(j);
    }

    ArrayAdapter<Integer> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            System.out.println("Selected item :: "+list.get(position));
            System.out.println("Selected item Pos :: "+position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
 int spinnerPosition = adapter.getPosition(yourStringValue);
 mSpinner.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
```